# Old Circular Metal Piece

Tags: plaster

I recently bought a house in norwood, oh and I was adding a new light fixture. Upon cutting a hole to fish the wires thru, I stumbled upon a circular metal piece that is covering about 45% of a stud. I was wondering if anyone could shed some light on this object. the house was built in the 1940's, and the plaster was/is in bad shape. I can email a picture. but cant upload it to computer.

Comment: A picture would be worth a million words here.

Comment: It is a reasonable guess to suggest that you have access to your email from the computer. If the device with the picture is able to email a picture why not simply email it to yourself so that you can access it from the computer. This is a common work-around for situations where direct upload capability is not available.